# override command line Spring properties with bootstrap.yml

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-context

i have a tomcat box , which has spring active profile set already, as a command line argument  every time a spring app is deployed through catalina.

i am using spring cloud config server , so in  config client i specify active profile in bootstrap.yml , but as i mention earlier it is overriden by tomcat command line argument .

how to override the command line argument passed through tomcat , with my boostrap.yml at the time of bootstrap context loading so that i can pass active profile from my bootstrap.yml to config server.

Tomcat set environment command (which i cannot change  as i dont have access)

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.library.path=/path -Dspring.profiles.active=e2"
```

bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: e2,cron
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8888
  application:
    name: heartbeat_monitor.
```

Comment: Can you share the bootstrap.yml file and the command line arguments used while running ?

Comment: added the boostrap.yml and tomcat command .
i want spring to pick up active profile from bootstrap.yml i.e. e2,cron .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command line argument(-Dspring.profiles.active=e2) will always override your properties file, no matter how many hardcoded profiles you specify in your yaml file. I would suggest you to add additional profile to be set programatically at the runtime and keep two property files with `-profilename` before the .yml extension.

This could be done as follows:

> ApplicationMain.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(DemoApplication.class);
    app.setAdditionalProfiles("cron");
    app.run(args);
}
```

> bootstrap-e2.yml

```
// Keep all the properties which is specific to e2 profile.
```

> bootstrap-cron.yml

```
   // Keep all the properties which is specific to cron profile.
```

In this way, you can keep both the profiles in use .But, if a property is common in both the bootstrap files, then program will pick the property from that bootstrap file whose `profile` matches with the runtime args : `-Dspring.profiles.active`